# DexArchiveBuilderException when running my AndoidTest, not when running my App

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

When I try to run my AndroidTest (which is testing my contentProvider), I get the following error messages during Building:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.6.0\...\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.Location
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.dbunit:dbunit:2.5.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
}
```

Funny thing is, my App itself can be run without any problems, so it seems it is test-related.

Your help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: Elsewhere it was suggested to add the following to my build.gradle, but that does not help.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I need the following dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

So the all use `implementation`. No need for `testImplementation` and `androidTestImplementation`.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me. My problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805814/failed-to-compile-project-with-excel-library-connected